# Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to fetch weather information from Yahoo using XHR in a Chrome extension:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=" + 250226 + "&u=c",
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

and I have requested the permission to cross-origin using this script:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    chrome.permissions.request({
        origins: ['*://weather.yahooapis.com/*']
    }, function(granted) {
        if (granted) {
            console.log("Success creating permission.");   //successful
    } else {
            console.log("Not successful.");
    }
});
```

However, it still gives me an error saying:

> `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=2502265&u=c. Origin chrome-extension://randomid is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

[image]

And I can't think of any reason why this is happening. Any idea?

Comment: I'm not much of a web developer, [but the documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html) doesn't seem to specify that wildcards are okay.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declare_permissions.html

Comment: I probably can't contribute any more (not a web developer etc) but the documentation that says "match patterns" seems to be for `permissions` not [`origins`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions.html#apiReference).

Comment: @ta.speot.is - "match patterns" is for `origins`, because only the a list of permissions can be put in `permissions`. Even I removed `*` it is still not working. :(

Comment: Considering [this sample extension by Google](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/permissions/extension-questions/options.js), could you give `http://weather.yahooapis.com/` (without `*`) a try?

Comment: @Passerby - Your link really helped me a lot... I tried `chrome.permissions.contains` to see if I actually have the permission and it returns `false`. After another careful look in my codes I found out that I have forgotten to put `"`s between the different permissions I already have before. Silly me. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Chrome-Extention have a manifest file? It seems like this is the problem, you should also set your cross-origin permission there.

Seems that the randomId mention is related to the extension not being assigned a proper extension ID.

Comment: Hi joseeight, thanks for your answer, but I have found out where the problem is at already... I mentioned it in the comment section above. Also `random_id` is just a place holder I put in so that there won't be weird characters all over the question.